# Is overturning Citizens United part of the Green Party Platform?

Tags: united-states, campaign-finance, green-party

Is over turning [*Citizen's United v. FEC*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citizens_United_v._FEC) officially part of the [Green Party's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_Party_of_the_United_States) platform? Does it include other mentions changing campaign finance laws?

Answer (score 3):

## Yes, it's in the plank but not explicitly

The Green Party's platform can be found online. You can view the [July 2020 platform here](https://d3n8a8pro7vhmx.cloudfront.net/gpus/pages/4899/attachments/original/1605570177/Platform-combined.pdf?1605570177). Though it doesn't mention *"Citizen's United"* explicitly, it does propose solutions that are inconsistent with Supreme Court's decision,

Such as public financing of elections in 1(a).

> Provide **full public financing** of federal, state and local elections, including
> free and **equal radio and television time on the public airwaves** for all
> ballot-qualified candidates and parties.

And further, an explicit prohibition of corporate donations,

> Prohibit corporations from spending to influence elections, preferably by
> constitutional amendment abolishing granting corporations constitutional
> rights guaranteed to natural persons, or as a condition of receipt of a
> corporate charter by federal chartering of corporations.

Note all of this is highly relevant because the conditional amendment is required to overturn the Citizen's United verdict which is a Supreme Court's decision.

---

It's also in their ["four pillars"](https://www.gp.org/4_pillars),

> *We demand public financing of elections, open debates, and more representative voting systems.*